# Why can't I filter an IQueryable like I can with a List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm refactoring a project a little bit and have come back to a problem that I never got solved in the past.  I am trying to perform multiple filters on a query of an EF Core db.

In the past I had tried to setup a series of Where statements that did a check on if the filter statement was null OR by matching the filter.

This returned a nullReferenceException somewhere in the query.  I resolved that issue by running my query without the filters and then applying the filters to my List afterwards.

I came back and created a WhereIf extension and hoped it would maybe fix my issues while also making the code a little cleaner, but the same issue pops up.

I currently have four filters I am trying to run on the query, and it passes the initial filter fine, but if any of the other three filters are chosen, the query has a nullReferenceException.

This again works if I get a list from a general query and the first filter, and then subsequently apply the filters to my list.

This is what I'd like to do:

```
IQueryable<Film> films = _context.Films
    .Include(f => f.Media)
    .Include(f=> f.Audio)
    .Include(f => f.FilmGenres)
        .ThenInclude(fg => fg.Genre)
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchValue), f => f.Name.ToLower().Contains(vm.SearchValue.ToLower()))
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MediaFilter), f => f.Media.Name == vm.MediaFilter)
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.AudioFilter), f => f.Audio.Name == vm.AudioFilter)
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.GenreFilter), f => f.FilmGenres.Any(fg => fg.Genre != null && fg.Genre.Name == vm.GenreFilter));
```

Here is the WhereIf method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
        {
            // Performs a Where only when the condition is met

            if (condition)
            {
                source = source.Where(predicate);
                return source;
            }

            return source;
        }
```

The filter on vm.SearchValue goes through fine, and when I step through it, the value is a IQueryable as expected.  Once it hits any of the other filters, then it comes back with the nullReferenceException (when it finally gets to the ToList() later on).  If I look at the value of source prior to return, it shows it having the null exception in the Result View.

I have tried doing each line one by one (with a films = film.Where(...)).  I have tried skipping the WhereIf and just doing if statements and a standard Where, and all of this has the same result.

It is only when I create a List object, populated by a general query of the data, and then filter that List object that I get it to work.

So, what is the problem with filtering on an IQueryable in EF Core?  Is this not allowed, or am I doing something wrong?

Update: All of the Film objects do have Media/Audio/FilmGenre objects and everything has been Included.  And I have verified that items in the IQueryable source has all of these items prior to the Where statement in the WhereIf method.

I have tried separating each filter statement out separately, and that includes skipping the WhereIf method and using if statements as well.

Additionally, only one filter can be selected at a time (for now).  Those that aren't selected result in the condition being false and there is no problem.  It only hiccups when working on an active filter.  For example, I'll do an initial search that only checks the vm.SearchValue.  That will give me a list of Film's and options to filter and sort.  Then when I select to filter by Audio or Media, etc., I get the problem.

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at lambda_method(Closure , InternalEntityEntry )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.SimpleNonNullableDependentKeyValueFactory`1.TryCreateFromCurrentValues(InternalEntityEntry entry, TKey& key)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.WeakReferenceIdentityMap`1.CreateIncludeKeyComparer(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.IncludeCore(Object entity, INavigation navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Int32 currentNavigationIndex, Boolean queryStateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Boolean queryStateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.GroupJoinIncludeContext.Include(Object entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.GroupJoinIncludeContext.Include(Object entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.GroupJoinIncludeContext.Include(Object entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.GroupJoinIncludeContext.Include(Object entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_GroupJoin>d__26`4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__165`3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Images Below:

1. Here is source's Results View when going through the SearchValue filter prior to the Where statement in WhereIf
2. Here it is after that Where statement
3. Here it's going through the AudioFilter - predicate shown.
4. Here is the source prior to the Where statement when doing the AudioFilter - same as after the SearchValue filtering
5. And finally, after doing the Where when doing the Audio filtering

[image: Here is source's Results View when going through the SearchValue filter prior to the Where statement in WhereIf]

[image: Here it is after that Where statement]

[image: Here it's going through the AudioFilter - predicate shown.]

[image: Here is the source prior to the Where statement when doing the AudioFilter - same as after the SearchValue filtering]

[image: And finally, after doing the Where when doing the Audio filtering]

UPDATE: This has been resolved.  There was another check involving the application user that was causing a client side evaluation, that was moved and now the query works as intended.

Comment: Do all Films definitely have Media, Audio and FilmGenre linked entities? Are you .including them? I'd guess you need to check e.g. `f => (f.Media != null) && (f.Media.Name == vm.MediaFilter)`. But I'd guess the NPE here means this isn't being translated into SQL to execute on the database, as you probably want it to be.

Comment: Add each `WhereIf` one at a time. Something you are doing is causing EF Core to split the query and run part of it in LINQ to Objects (it isn't as capable as EF 6 at translating to SQL) and that is your core (npi) issue.

Comment: The way it's shown, it should work. There must be something causing client evaluation. What happens if you configure [Optional behavior: throw an exception for client evaluation
](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation)?

Comment: @Rup Yes, all of those items are included (and verified during debugging that they are present).

Comment: @NetMage It has been tested separately as well.

Comment: I find your "WhereIf" approach cumbersome and unpleasant to read. You could build much cleaner code by using the PredicateBuilder class of LINQKit for example. Apart that your code seems ok, as long as you're sure that all properties of Films are correctly instantiated, and also the same for your "vm" object when the predicate is actually executed. You could also use ?. operator to increase code robustness.

Comment: What happens if you call `_context.Films.ToList()`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I get a List of All the Films in the db.

Comment: Are you getting the NRE after the successive `WhereIf`s but before calling `.ToList()`? Or only after the `.ToList()`? If you call `.First()` (and assuming there is no sorting in your query) do you also get an NRE? You may need to pass successively larger values into `.Take` to find the exact object which is causing the problem. Also, could you include the stack trace of the NRE?

Comment: Try using variables instead of `vm.*`.  The expression-to-sql of EF core should be able expand such variables to their current value.  Or check if you're setting `vm` to `null` before you materialize/execute the query, or if you're disposing or resetting it.

Comment: And when tested separately, does adding any one cause the error, or only after a certain one, or...?

Comment: @acelent I have verified vm.* values.  And I have even tested with a hard-coded value.

Comment: @NetMage when tested separately, it shows up whenever it gets to the first filter value that is not null (except the SearchValue one).  So if I filter by the Audio, it will get all the objects with the SearchValue, skip over the Media one since it is null, and once it does the query inside the WhereIf on the Audio the NRE shows up.  It doesn't actually break the application until I do a ToList() later, but if I check the value of source before it returns from the WhereIf, I can see it.

Comment: @ZevSpitz The NRE shows up beore the WhereIf returns.  The application doesn't break until ToList() is called, but the NRE is there prior.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Added the stack trace.

Comment: Could you try to use calls that do not use methods like `.ToLower()`, `.Contains()` Just to try and exclude the case that for some reason the provider cannot give you the correct representation in sql. (I know its an edge case )

Comment: I don't think you understood. By testing separately, I mean comment out all the calls to `WhereIf` except one, and see what happens in that one case. I also don't think you understand how `IQueryable` works - an expression that returns an `IQueryable` does not evaluate any code - it just builds a data structure representing the query that will be executed when needed - such as in a `foreach`, after a `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`, etc.

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos The filter that actually uses .ToLower() and .Contains() is the one that goes through without a problem.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, I've tried only doing single filters, and I've stepped through the code, so I'm seeing when things occur.  See pictures added.

Comment: Try commenting out all `Include` / `ThenInclude` lines and see if it works. It would be nice if you can create a small console project which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think I got it figured out now.  It goes back to what you mentioned about client evaluation.  I forgot to add on here another Where that was being performed based on the User of the application.  Once I took that out and put it elsewhere, it worked. I'm still not sure about the timing of everything and why the first filter based on SearchValue didn't cause the issue as well, but that does seem to be the culprit.  That's my bad for not showing that bit on here.  Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I always just use a simple OR operator instead of WhereIf

```
 IQueryable<Film> films = _context.Films
    .Include(x => x.Media)
    .Include(x => x.Audio)
    .Include(x => x.FilmGenres)
    .ThenInclude(g => g.Genre)
                .Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchValue) || f.Name.ToLower().Contains(vm.SearchValue.ToLower()))
                .Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MediaFilter) || f.Media.Name == vm.MediaFilter)
                .Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.AudioFilter) || f.Audio.Name == vm.AudioFilter)
                .Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.GenreFilter) || (f.FilmGenres.Any(fg => fg.Genre != null && fg.Genre.Name == vm.GenreFilter)));
```

Comment: That is what I had tried before (last year), and that came up with the same problem, with the same fix...getting a list first and then doing the filter.

Comment: Is it possible that FilmGenres, Media, and Audio are null?  I know if using .net core, lazy loading is not enabled by default so you would need to call include.

Comment: No, they have values.  I can try narrowing my searchValue so it's a very small number of objects and verifying each object manually.

Comment: I just verified that the objects existing prior to applying the AudioFilter did have all the necessary values populated.

Comment: Ahh ok... Unsure what is happening then to get null reference.

Answer (score -1):

This answer's off the cuff and is a bit of guesswork on my part, so I apologize if it's not helpful.

Anyway, a couple things are standing out to me.

First, your WhereIf() function - it's not quite doing what a Where() would do.  Where() takes a source and returns a second source where the recordset is winnowed down.  Notably, it doesn't *change* the original datasource at all.  Well, your WhereIf() is trying to do that - it's changing the 'source' variable that's being passed in to the function.  I did some googling, and the IQueryable *doesn't* look like it's immutable which means it can be changed without creating a new class instance, so I'm not positive that this line of code isn't screwing up the foundation its building off of:

```
source = source.Where(predicate);
```

... it would explain the results you're getting.  The first 'WhereIf' with a true condition works, but the subsequent one doesn't - because the first one messed with the base object it was working off of.  At the very least, you should change it to 'return source.Where(predicate)', simply for code clarity (since your existing code makes it look like its *trying* to change it.)

Second, have you tried breaking the statement up?  I mean, something like this:

```
var results = SomeLinq.SomeStatement(a => something(a))
        .Where(b => b == something)
        .Where(c => c == something)
```

... is the same thing as:

```
var mainQueryable = SomeLinq.SomeStatement(a => something(a));
var filtered = mainQueryable.Where(b => b == something);
var results = filtered.Where(c => c == something);
```

Which in turn would let you simplify the picture down for LINQ:

```
IQueryable<Film> films = _context.Films
    .Include(f => f.Media)
    .Include(f=> f.Audio)
    .Include(f => f.FilmGenres)
    .ThenInclude(fg => fg.Genre);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchValue)) films = films.Where(f => f.Equals(vm.SearchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MediaFilter)) films = films.Where(f => f.Media.Name == vm.MediaFilter);
// etc...
```

... so the final LINQ statement doesn't have superfluous WHERE clauses that don't actually filter anything down.

Anyway, hope these help out a bit.

Comment: I have actually tried all of that (except for using different variables for each separation).  The WhereIf did originally return source.Where(predicate), but I added the other line for debugging so that I could see what was being returned.  

It's also important to note, that before I even used a WhereIf, using .Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MediaFilter) || f.Media.Name == vm.MediaFilter) had the same result.

Comment: Actually, thinking that the assigment to `source` is an issue shows a lack of understanding of how C# works. `source` is an object reference, and re-assigning it to point to a different object does nothing to the original object. See the source for [`Where`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,fceeefcb290fb6aa) for (functionally) the same thing.